# Cannot compile Visual Studio's template for UMDF USB drivers

Tags: usb, driver, umdf

The line:

```
   #include "device.tmh"
```

appears underlined in red, and an error is reported that "the source file cannot be opened" (I'm translating from Spanish here, the wording might be different in English).

Also, words like:

```
 TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER
```

all appear underlined in red. "The identifier is undefined".

What's happening?

Comment: This is a flaw of Visual Studio. It should compile although those lines are underlined in red. Please provide compiler error messages (Click the "output" tab in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked 4 years ago but for anyone who comes across this question in future, even uninstalling and installing the visual studio didn't seem to help.

It worked for me when I installed **spectre migrated libs** as instructed in [this tutorial's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) step 1.

The new project was built successfully after installing the above mentioned libs and running visual studio as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

As @arminb stated this is probably a flaw within Visual Studio. After going to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` and right-clicking on Microsoft Visual Studio and click on change, a simple Repair can solve this issue.